# Context.Usuario no retorna los registros al establecer una FK null ASP Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Buenas tengo un proyecto en net core 3 mvc, donde tengo un modelo Usuario y un modelo Asignatura. El usuario puede o no tener una asignatura relacionada por lo tanto la fk de usuario a asignatura puede ser null, el problema esta en que si es null el context no me devuelve los registros de la base de datos, al contrario de si tiene un valor definido que si los devuelve. Adjunto imagenes.

Modelo Usuario:

```
 public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    public String Nombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
    public String Telefono { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El celular es obligatorio")]
    public String Celular { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El email es obligatorio")]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rol")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El rol es un parámetro requerido.")]
    public int RolId { get; set; }
    public Rol Rol { get; set; }

    public int AsignaturaId { get; set; }
    public Asignatura Asignatura { get; set; }
}
```

Modelo Asignatura:

```
 public class Asignatura
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    public String Nombre { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Accion index del Controller usuario donde cargo el listado:

```
 //Http Get Index
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        
        IEnumerable<Usuario> listUsuarios = _context.Usuario
                                            .Include(d => d.Rol)
                                            .Include(a => a.Asignatura);

        return View(listUsuarios);
    }
```

[image: Composicion de la tabla usuario]

[image: registro de un usuario con el campo asignaturaID null]

[image: Listado que devuelve en este caso, vacio]

[image: registro de un usuario con el campo asignaturaID con un valor]

[image: Listado que devuelve en este caso, con el registro]

Vista index del Usuario:

```
@model IEnumerable<PruebaMVC1.Models.Usuario>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lista de usuarios";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">

    @if (TempData["mensaje"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            @TempData["mensaje"]
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>Lista de Usuarios</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <a class="btn btn-success" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Usuarios">Nuevo</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @if(Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-hover mt-4">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Nombre)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Telefono)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Celular)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Rol.Nombre)</td>
                        <td>Acciones</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Id</td>
                        <td>@item.Nombre</td>
                        <td>@item.Telefono</td>
                        <td>@item.Celular</td>
                        <td>@item.Email</td>
                        <td>@item.Rol.Nombre</td>

                        <td>
                            <a asp-controller="Usuarios" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                            <a asp-controller="Usuarios" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No existen usuarios</p>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tú dices `el problema esta en que si es null el context no me devuelve los registros` Te tira un error??? y otra cosa, tu procedimiento fue crear tus clases y luego ir a la base de datos y poner check a `allow nulls` ??

Comment: Hola @Yussef, gracias x responder. Exacto si el valor es null el contexto no me devuelve los registros, error no veo q devuelva, incluso termina el proceso y devuelve la vista. El procedimiento fue crear el modelo, la migración, dentro de la migración especifique que podía ser null la columna AsignaturaID y le establecí null como valor x defecto.

Comment: Creo que tengo la respuesta, pero debes agregar ese código que pusiste en imagen como texto, porque 1) Van a cerrar la pregunta en cualquier momento, ya que no se permiten las imágenes de código y principalmente por 2) Yo debo comprobar que mi respuesta sea correcta y tengo que transcribir todo ese código, en cambio para ti significa copiar/pegar solamente

Comment: Vale no sabía gracias, modifico el post ahora

Comment: Lo soluciono mil gracias. Como pongo tu respuesta como correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El modelo en C# (las clases) debe coincidir con el modelo de la base de datos. En tu caso tienes que AsignaturaId es un entero (recuerda que un entero no acepta valores nulos) y en la base de datos tienes que si lo acepta.

Para corregir esto, debes convertir el int en `Nullable` esto se hace agregando el sufijo `?`

Ejemplo:

```
 public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    public String Nombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
    public String Telefono { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El celular es obligatorio")]
    public String Celular { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El email es obligatorio")]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rol")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El rol es un parámetro requerido.")]
    public int RolId { get; set; }
    public Rol Rol { get; set; }

    public int? AsignaturaId { get; set; } //<-- Cambio aquí
    public Asignatura? Asignatura { get; set; } //<-- No es 100% necesario, pero rigurosamente debería haberlo 
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias me salvaste la vida.